# Dynamically assigning object properties based on the value of an array of other objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

Okay so I know the title can be a bit confusing, so let me explain.

I have the following interfaces and an array of `Items[]`:

```js
interface Items {
    step: number;
    keyName: string;
    value: string;
}

interface ReturnData {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
    baz: string;
}

const items: Items[] = [
    { step: 1, keyName: 'foo', value: 'fooVal' },
    { step: 2, keyName: 'bar', value: 'barVal' },
    { step: 3, keyName: 'baz', value: 'bazVal' },
];
```

Now imagine I want function that accepts `Items[]` as a parameter, loops over the `items`, and for each item assigns a new property with a key of `keyName` and a value of `value` to a new object of type `ReturnData`, and then it finally returns that object as a promise.

For demonstration purposes I am using `setInterval` here, but the same would work with a `for loop` or other method.

```js
const myFunc = (items: Items[]): Promise<ReturnData> => {
    let index = 0;
    let returnData: ReturnData = { foo: '', bar: '', baz: '' };

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {

            /*
                at index 0: items[index].keyName = 'foo' and items[index].value = 'fooVal'
                at index 1: items[index].keyName = 'bar' and items[index].value = 'barVal'
                at index 2: items[index].keyName = 'baz' and items[index].value = 'bazVal'
            */

            returnData[items[index].keyName] = items[index]?.value;

            if (items[index]?.step === items.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve(returnData);
            }
            else {
                index += 1;
            }

        }, 250);
    })
}

(async () => {
    const myResult = await myFunc(items);
    console.log('myResult value is:', myResult);

    /* myResult value is: { foo: 'fooVal', bar: 'barVal', baz: 'bazVal' } */
})();
```

In plain javascript this function would run properly and return `myResult` as expected. But in Typescript I am getting the following error messages when I try to dynamically assign properties to `returnData` at each iteration of my `setInterval`.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ReturnData'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ReturnData'.ts(7053)
```

and

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

I have recently started learning Typescript, so my question is, how do I make Typescript understand what is happening here so that it doesn't throw the an error. I know a quick and dirty trick is to assign type `any` to my `returnData` object to get rid of the errors, but that wouldn't be exactly "type-safe" if that is the correct terminology. What is a better way to go about and make typescript happy?

**[Full code example at TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYGdkG8BQyRyWkADgFzIgCuGARtANyHEDWEAngHJwYRVSUUAHMWxZADc4AGxoCSYYSDH4AvvnyhIsRCgBKEMDSggAInDBw8rIjAD29wUtHji9OFGfLVEjwC9vV3VNBHsQUmRgTCwqdAhsAG0AXWQAXmRE2zxFCEpkAEYAGmQOHj4FAHIHe0qS6TkqmoA1WUrkNSLs3Fz8gCYSst5+KkqPKDqpWXlR8daZds7u3qoAZkGuYaqAyYaZ5DG4f3nFruSWfDCIsGQMTgAxGhAEdOQACmiE2LQYlIBKKgABSg9gwwCwEAAPIZjKYLFYAHzpJEECQyIxREAAEwgAA9XgAGNxEdE3KBGEzmSxwKgwynw6wZHo1UaTcaskoBVkdC4ScmwkDUCAAd2QwNB4Igb3JWHsMkkKDSKOyEiukW00AarwhYFQ4E1sjebz+yJsEnNxAA9AAqFUW82WTE4-EEqifJKgZ3JAB0Qwqr2qjnacGxUV+nrxPr2ioOLTadvtxEdEfxBTd4exkd9m39GUOE2QIaxYa+iRTUemMfzJwTicLNxTyD66dL5ez5X4AZ2hdD7qwZczuIrjS7RxrdeI1stmgnRH59OpZYzXoAhO2tqkMn2B16APze6O82fAGDvbfl-ekPLpNJbmLe9EqMAACxNqNnqvRnj1OgaH31UANH8xIfsgMpygq0oUnC1LAbWEgaB+EAyBCZqgUQjYANQZAUIGJhotadE2ACsBJwQhfwhPgbxwFgnDPO8JpKmhRBqjcdyGFgNAyDcGRwMKcDRLcDxPAgHwxORxBqnKEAPvYIhvJUHEQFxPFTCO4IUJMymqWAcFqH8xpMEAA)**

Comment: Note that interfaces are typically singular: `interface Item`.

Comment: @tokland you mean that I shouldn't use plural form when I am naming interfaces that are a single object rather than an array?

Comment: Yep. `type Items = Item[]` is ok, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating this line should solve your issue:

Issue is that typescript can not associate they keyName of string type as being a key of ReturnData.

```
interface Items {
    step: number;
    keyName: keyof ReturnData; // only if you expect that ReturnData keyName will always belong to ReturnData 
    value: string;
}
```

[typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYGdkG8BQyRyWkADgFzIgCuGARtANyHEDWEAngHJwYRUOnAPYxkAJQhgaUEABE4YOE2QB6VcmEgANp2TAxImsggAPMhARhkYABaKJUmfMVxkQ3v2QB3YNu3IcNrecJw4jNpaAOY2wo7SsgpKyKxEAG5BNAIkYFCgUSwAvvj4oJCwiCiSCS7JBMTIMMLCVKR5IAWpyPRwUK25%20SwNPQBe-e2dxfgIWqT6mFhU6BDYANoAusgAvMirXbg5EJTIAIwANO5cntkA5E3CNxcZ2llUd80AakE3yIVn%204djgAmC4ePi3HpQR7IZ6vZA3SFfbQ-P4A0hHKgAZlBV3Bb1G0NhELgIyRKP%206xY01m1gwnAAYjQQAhtsgABTABZLBYbACUVAAClBhBhgFgIAAearOJJwAB82wV9WI2ik%20hAABMzKyAAxDFVqqBORKuKjSk3JHYHe5vaGQ20XUa235UhpGmrUCDeZBCkViiBso1YYTaNIoLZKroNGYgOZlaDPVnisCocAJoJstm8xV4KMNYiqABUefz%20YcoC1pmQOqonJWWFWFbM6wAdGCvDt3g9Apr5vXG5rmy2iayu2SS6XiOXB1WTrWeU3TK32%20H4ZCfnBe3W1ovWyPO4jvhPJ4FrIvkED5-3d23cR21ySN1uFzO95lVwiSeOTw1C6oSj%20xDujKrirByL6VusACEt48OCvKbDs24NruAD8w7vq6gH6GI4HXq%206HomQ2xbEhCwtqqHR2NmyrYcQCCqr0qblM8HJplAzy8vqdFEEGIZhoGxq1HAXHHsQxR0RA2jirmPHEOeADUOwnNxP5TCefwXgArDqokNIUvL4FMbJwFgnDMuy2YRrJ9E0sgdKSFgNDaNYOxwCEnL2QyTIIHh2B6bZsYhhAFHCFEbI3A5EBOS5MLvvoizQlFMVgKJBlZkwQA)
or

```
 returnData[(items[index]!.keyName) as keyof ReturnData] = items[index]?.value ?? '';
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYGdkG8BQyRyWkADgFzIgCuGARtANyHEDWEAngHJwYRVSUUAHMWxZADc4AGxoCSYYSDH4AvvnyhIsRCgBKEMDSggAInDBw8rIjAD29wUtHji9OFGfLVEjwC9vV3VNBHsQUmRgTCwqdAhsAG0AXWQAXmRE2zxFCEpkAEYAGmQOHj4FAHIHe0qS6TkqmoA1WUrkNSLs3Fz8gCYSst5%20KkqPKDqpWXlR8daZds7u3qoAZkGuYaqAyYaZ5DG4f3nFruSWfDCIsGQMTgAxGhAEdOQACmiE2LQYlIBKKgABSg9gwwCwEAAPIZjKYLFYAHzpJEECQyIxREAAEwgAA9XgAGNxEdE3KBGEzmSxwKgwynw6wZHo1UaTcaskoBVkdC4ScmwkDUCAAd2QwNB4Igb3JWHsMkkKDSKOyEiukW00AarwhYFQ4E1sjebz%20yJsEnNxAA9AAqFUW82WTE4-EEqifJKgZ3JAB0Qwqr2qjnacGxUV%20nrxPr2ioOLTadvtxEdEfxBTd4exkd9m39GUOE2QIaxYa%20iRTUemMfzJwTicLNxTyD66dL5ez5X4AZ2hdD7qwZczuIrjS7RxrdeI1stmgnRH59OpiQ%20Ga9AEJ21sTXAcGV7DBkHS4dTUhk%20wOvQB%20b3R3mz4D75etwfJK%20kPLpNKnmLe9EqMAACxNVFZ1VdFPD1HQGg%20fUoAaP5iRA5AZTlBVpQpI8rHg2sJA0ECIBkCEzUQohGwAagyAoEMTDRa06JsAFYCSwnC-hCfA3m3ThnneE0lSIog1RuO5DCwGgZBuDI4GFOBoluB4ngQR9sGY4g1TlCAf3sEQ3kqYSIFE8SphHcEKEmPSDLALC1D%20Y0mCAA)

Comment: This works indeed, but it appears that for some reason I had `noUncheckedIndexedAccess: true` in `tsconfig.json` and if it's enabled, it still throws the same error. Is there any way around that? Also, thanks for your answer. I suppose this kinda makes sense but and I just lack enough practice and experience with Typescript to notice something that appears obvious.

Comment: you just need to provide the value when items[index]?.value is undefined
`items[index]?.value ?? '';`

Comment: Oh right, I did notice you edit, sorry about that. This works pretty nicely indeed, appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Just change your interface like this, using `keyof` operator.

```
interface Items {
    step: number;
    keyName: keyof ReturnData;
    value: string;
}
```

**keyName is now:** "foo" | "bar" | "baz"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a quick follow-up question if you don't mind. Instead of changing the `Items` interface, can I somehow change the `ReturnData` interface to make this work?

Comment: Glad. If there is, I am not aware of it. What vaira posted is another good way with `as` keyword. But I don't think only changing  ReturnData can fix this

Comment: Yeah, I looked at his solution too, was just wondering if there is another way to go about this. Thanks anyways!